# Async function not waiting for await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, jestjs

I have many async functions where i import a json from a file and then set the fields. I have an await for importing the json. Earlier it used to execute sequentially by awaiting for the json and then manipulating the data. I used to use Mocha before and recently started migrating to Jest which is when all my tests and functions have started breaking.

I am not sure if I understand the async functions correctly. But it used to work fine before and not anymore. Below is the example:

```
async build_transaction_request({reference=util.id_generator(), type="XYZ", amount=25, currency="USD", timestamp=util.timestamp_millis()}={}){
    let transactions = await config_util.get_payload("transactions")
    let x_transaction = transactions.xTransaction
    x_transaction.reference = reference
    x_transaction.type = type
    x_transaction.amount = amount
    x_transaction.currency = currency
    x_transaction.timestamp = timestamp
    return x_transaction
}
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'reference' of undefined

Below are the other two functions:

```js
async load_data(file_path) {
  await delete require.cache[require.resolve(file_path)]
  let data = await require(file_path);
  return data
}

async get_payload(file_name) {
  let payload = await this.load_data(this.root_dir + '/resources/payload/' + file_name + ".json")
  return payload
}
```

Below is the code from my test that invokes the build_transaction_request function:

```js
test('Test xyz returns 201', async() => {
      //......some code.....

      var[instruction, x_transaction, token] = await Promise.all([

          helper.build_instruction_request({
            type: "CURRENCY",
            value: value,
            rate: rate
          }),
          helper.build_transaction_request({
            amount: amount
          }),
          helper.build_token_request(token_id)
      ]);
});
```

Comment: Does this `get_payload` return a Promise object?  Second, are you sure this `transactions.xTransaction` does not return undefined?

Comment: For starters, have you dropped in a `console.log(transactions);` to see what that object actually looks like?

Comment: @Pointy - If i run a single test, it all works well. But if run the test suite, tests start failing and the console.log(transactions); prints undefined.

Comment: Then it sounds like you may want to look into what `config_util.get_payload()` is doing.

Comment: @Ele - Yes the get_payload is an async function as well so it should return a promise if i am not wrong. I have edited the description and added those two functions.

Comment: @Pointy - I have added the get_payload function in the description.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, you're not getting a promise object.

Comment: @aby Please also post the code which invokes the function `build_transaction_request`.  It seems you're assigning a default value, but during invocation, you're not passing valid parameters.

Comment: @dvsoukup - I have added the test snippet that invokes the 'build_transaction_request'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that `await config_util.get_payload("transactions")` returns an object once resolved, which is either missing the `xTransaction` property, or it's manually set with `undefined`. The code will the blow up once you attempt a property off of `undefined`, which is what you're doing with: `x_transaction.reference = reference`.  It's like saying: `undefined.reference = reference`....  Thus that is the point at which the code goes boom.  You can't assign a value to something that doesn't exist in memory.

Your `get_payload` is simply resolving a promise and returning that result, based on some file path you've provide to `load_data`.

Did you look at the parameter you're passing into `load_data`?

```
let payload = await this.load_data(this.root_dir + '/resources  /payload/' + file_name + ".json")
```

You have a space in there for one, so it's probably not correct.  Whatever you're feeding to there, it's not finding the json...

Comment: Thanks @dvsoukup for detailed explanation. I agree the problem lies with getting the data. this file is being accessed by multiple function and then maniplulating the data which i think modifies the imported file at runtime. Could there be a clash/race condition since i am also deleting the cache before importing it?

Comment: I updated my answer because... well I'm silly and the issue didn't initially pop out at me.  Ooops!  :(  The culprit is the file name you're passing in.  You need to double check the file path you're sending in.

Comment: that was a copy paste error. I have modified it. The file path is correct in my code. The thing is it works ok if i execute only one test. Also if you notice i am using Promise.all which executes promises in parallel and both the promises are accessing the same file.

Answer (score 0):

So i figured out the problem. I changed the way i imported the json. now i am using readFileSync(file_path); The problem is gone now. So i believe it was due to accessing same file by multiple functions at same time. Thank you very much everyone.